# Different date format and one locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, rails-i18n

I use `I18n.t('date.formats.default')` for date formatting.

The issue is that in different countries there are **different date formats**, but **one english locale**.

For example '**%m.%d.%Y**' fo **US** and '**%d.%m.%Y**' for **Australia**

I need the ideas how to handle with it.

Comment: One solution is to use the HTML5 date inputs instead of a text column. That eliminates the need for handling different input formats.

Comment: Always use an iso date format for persistence, i.e. storing in datastore, and if you operate across multiple timezones, store as UTC. Then you can convert in your models or views accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

While you might simply use something else for date formats, the easiest drop-in solution would be to store *all* possible variants in the same string and on retrieval do (assuming the country code is known):

```
'date.formats.default': 'US[%m.%d.%Y],AU[%d.%m.%Y]'

code = 'AU'
format = I18n.t('date.formats.default')
format[/(?<=#{code}\[).*?(?=\])/] || format
#⇒ "%d.%m.%Y"
```

The latter `|| format` is needed to support normal format, without brackets.

---

If you don’t like regular expressions, store the JSON there, containing hash `{CODE => FORMAT}`, parse it and retrieve the value.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is more convenient way to use different locales.

For example `en-AU.yml`, `en-US.yml`, `en-CA.yml` etc.? Especially i18n supports this.

Australia has different time format too.

Every time you have to take into account all these nuances for each country.

Using different locales simplifies this.

Comment: Can I have only difference and common other translations? It is not a good way to dublicate plenty of the same translations and keep them actual.

Comment: Aleksei gave you a wonderful trick. But imagine if you have 100 countries with different languages, each with its own characteristics (not only date/time formats). If you edit your code, it will be ugly. It is better to duplicate some data in different locales, for example, using a script for this. There is also such a solution: https://github.com/kipcole9/rails-i18n-translation-inheritance-helper

Comment: @mechnicov that gem has not been updated in 10 years. Does it actually work with any relatively recent version of rails?

Comment: I did not need to use it. I just gave it to you to understand the idea (look at the gem source code). You can try to use gem as is or use this idea yorself

Comment: @mechnicov "Can I have only difference and common other translations?" yes you can, probably you can use something like https://github.com/ruby-i18n/i18n/blob/master/lib/i18n/backend/fallbacks.rb